# Как заставить телеграм бота отправить новое сообщение по нажатию инлайн кнопки, предварительно удалив старое

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Есть телеграм бот на aiogram. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию инлайн кнопки он удалял предыдущее сообщение и отправлял новое с новым инлайн меню кнопок. Но он этого не делает. Ещё и выдаётся ошибка после запуска бота: aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running, другие приложения не открыты, работает один экземпляр бота. Вот первая команда:`@dp.message_handler(Command("start"))

```
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("", reply_markup=choice)`
```

К ней вот такой набор кнопок:

```
choice = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
inline_keyboard=[
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='katalog')
    ]
]
```

)

И ещё одна команда:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='katalog')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(cache_time=60)
    callback.data = call.data
    logging.info(f"call = {callback_data}")
    await call.message.answer('', reply_markup=katalog_tovarov)
```

К ней такое меню инлайн кнопок:

```
katalog_tovarov = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
inline_keyboard=[
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='oil'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='soda')
    ]
]
```

)
И дальше бот перестаёт работать, ничего не отправляет. Просто не знаю, что надо писать

Answer (score 2):

Можно удалять любое сообщение с помощью delete_message, а следующим сообщением отправлять новую клавиатуру

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('katalog'))
async def get_katalog_kb(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
    if call.data == 'katalog':
        await call.message.answer('Новое сообщение', reply_markup=katalog_tovarov)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете редактировать сообщение. С помощью `callback.message.edit_text`. Примерно такой код:

```py
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token='ВАШТОКЕН')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def load_znak(message: types.Message):
    choice = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text='Каталог', callback_data='katalog')
            ]
        ])
    await message.answer("Выберите", reply_markup=choice)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='katalog')
async def answer(callback: CallbackQuery):
    katalog_tovarov = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text='Масло', callback_data='oil'),
                InlineKeyboardButton(text='Сода', callback_data='soda')
            ]
        ])
    await callback.message.edit_text("Выбран каталог выберите товар.", reply_markup=katalog_tovarov)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ошибка которую вы получаете должна выдаваться если запущено два polling-а если у вас запущен только 1 то попробуйте сменить токен бота.